# Getting "an error occurred while running subprocess ng" error when updating code from ionic 3 to ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I developed my project in Ionic 3. It's working well in the Ionic 3 platform. I tried to update my code to Ionic 4, at which point I am facing this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/providers/nav-controller.d.ts(13,29): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/providers/nav-controller.d.ts(16,29): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/providers/platform.d.ts(7,51): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/providers/platform.d.ts(10,18): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
```

Comment: If those are provider files, Ionic 4 now uses services instead. Take a look here. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3435

Comment: in ionic 4 i used services. i didn't add providers

Comment: You may need to create a new, empty project and add those services in one by one to make sure they are structured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused because you don't installed all dependencies than you need to development an app in Ionic

To works you need run in your console

```
npm i @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest
```